# How can I cluster similar type of sentences based on their context and extract keywords from them

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, semantics, ibm-watson, text-analysis

I wanted to cluster sentences based on their context and extract common keywords from similar context sentences.

For example
1. I need to go to home 
2. I am eating 
3. He will be going home tomorrow 
4. He is at restaurant

Sentences 1 and 3 will be similar with keyword like go and home and maybe it's synonyms like travel and house .

Pre existing API will be helpful like using IBM Watson somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API actually is doing what you are exactly asking for (Clustering sentences + giving key-words):
http://www.rxnlp.com/api-reference/cluster-sentences-api-reference/

Unfortunately the algorithm used for clustering and the for generating the key-words is not available.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RapidMiner](https://rapidminer.com) with [Text Processing Extension](https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_text).

Insert each sentence in a seperate file and put them all in a folder.

Put the operators and make a design like below.
[image]

Click on the Process Documents from files operator and in the right bar side choose "Edit list" on "Text directories" field. Then choose the folder that contains your files.

Double click on Process Documents from files operator and in the new window add the operators like below design(just the ones you need).

[image]

Then run your process.